# Return function is called only once in NextJS web app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my nextjs app I am trying to create a slider where I display a different component each time the next button is clicked. This is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ResiliationForm from './ResiliationForm';
import ResiliationUserData from './ResiliationUserData';

const slidePages = [
    {"id": 0, "page": "resiliationForm"},
    {"id": 1, "page": "resiliationUserDate"},
    {"id": 2, "page": "resiliationReview"},
]

const ResiliationSlider = ({ ...props }) => {
    props.currentPage = slidePages[0];

    const onNextClicked = value => {
        let currentPage = props.currentPage.id;
        props.currentPage = slidePages[currentPage + 1];
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {props.currentPage.id === 0 && <ResiliationForm key={props.currentPage.id} data={props.data} onNextClicked={onNextClicked}/>}
            {props.currentPage.id === 1 && <ResiliationUserData key={props.currentPage.id} data={props.data} onNextClicked={onNextClicked}/>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ResiliationSlider;
```

The `onNextClicked` is being called. I am chaning the current page in the props, but only the first page is shown. It seems that the return function is called only once. Can I force the element to be updated when the props is updated?

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is designed for that. After rendering component && the `value`(a.k.a dependency) has changed , then execute `useEffect` function. Otherwise, skip the whole `useEffect` function.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

const ResiliationSlider = ({ ...props }) => {
    props.currentPage = slidePages[0];

    const onNextClicked = value => {
        let currentPage = props.currentPage.id;
        props.currentPage = slidePages[currentPage + 1];
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        onNextClicked(value)
    }, [value])  

    return (
        <div>
            {props.currentPage.id === 0 && <ResiliationForm key={props.currentPage.id} data={props.data} onNextClicked={onNextClicked}/>}
            {props.currentPage.id === 1 && <ResiliationUserData key={props.currentPage.id} data={props.data} onNextClicked={onNextClicked}/>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ResiliationSlider;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `useState` hook to track the state inside the component, rather than modifying the props. Changing the state will trigger a re-render.

```js
const ResiliationSlider = ({ ...props }) => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(slidePages[0])

    const onNextClicked = value => {
        let currentPage = currentPage.id
        setCurrentPage(slidePages[currentPage + 1])
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {currentPage.id === 0 && <ResiliationForm key={currentPage.id} data={props.data} onNextClicked={onNextClicked}/>}
            {currentPage.id === 1 && <ResiliationUserData key={currentPage.id} data={props.data} onNextClicked={onNextClicked}/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```